# Angular routerlink not working with lazyloading modules

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to figure out lazyloading modules, which I have working. What doesn't work is `routerlink=` in my nav. A normal `href='`' does work though. I have a footer that links to a privacy page and a terms page, and they work fine with router link.

The full repo is available here: https://github.com/mjhandy/ng16Prototype

Here's my nav code snippet

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="/pages/typography" >Typography</a>
</li>          
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" routerlink="papges/typography" >Typography</a>
</li>
```

So as mentioned, the href link works fine.

Here is my app-router

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) 
  },
  { 
    path: 'privacy-policy', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.module').then(m => m.PrivacyPolicyModule) 
  },
  { 
    path: 'terms-conditions', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/terms/terms.module').then(m => m.TermsModule) 
  },
  { 
    path: 'pages/typography', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/typography/typography.module').then(m => m.TypographyModule) 
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now from the privacy-policy component I have the following files (excluding the obvious ones)

1. typography.component.ts

There is nothing here:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-typography',
  templateUrl: './typography.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./typography.component.scss']
})
export class TypographyComponent {

}
```

2. typography.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { TypographyComponent } from './typography.component';
import { TypographyRoutingModule } from './typography-routing.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TypographyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TypographyRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class TypographyModule { }
```

3. typography-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TypographyComponent } from './typography.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: TypographyComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TypographyRoutingModule { }
```

If this is the wrong way to ask, please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

The end goal is learning the best method of implement module lazy loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspecting your project, your `HeaderComponent` is a standalone component, so you can't make it inherit the `imports` of your `AppModule`

That's why you need to add `RouterModule` in your standalone component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports : [ MatIconModule, LoginComponent,RouterModule]
})
export class HeaderComponent {

}
```

Comment: Bingo. I had a feeling it would be something simple and I just needed to ask.

Cheers mate!